# How to writting a performant method with list object and mutliple if conditions with java 8

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-17

I have a method which return a list of Competition based on condition. I can have multiple condition and i want to have the best way to perform this method by using java 8 .
this is my method :

```
public static final String COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 = "compet1";
public static final String COMPETITION_AGE_30_40 = "compet2";
  
  public List<Competition> getCompetitionss(String competAge) {
    if (COMPETITION_AGE_18_30.equals(competAge)) {
      return List.of(
          CompetitionNatation,
          CompetitionFoot,
          CompetitionHand,
          CompetitionNatation);
    } else if (COMPETITION_AGE_30_40.equals(competAge)) {
      return List.of(
      CompetitionRoller
      );
    } else {
      return List.of();
    }
  }
```

how can i refactor this method with the best way

Comment: Looks like you can put the conditions as a field in the `Competition` class. and put all Competitions in a list as comList; then `comList.stream().filter( c -> Objects.equals(c.getAge(), competAge).toList()`. something like this.

Comment: Hi @exudong can you write a complete code example please

Comment: Can you share your Competition class/enum ?

Comment: Why do you tag your question with “java-17” when only want a Java 8 solution?

Comment: Do you want only Java 8, or *at least* Java 8?

Comment: Is `Competition` an enum?

Comment: What happens when the age is 30?  Is that intentional?

Comment: Why not just pass the minimum and maximum ages to the method, like `public List<Competition> getCompetitions(int minAge, int maxAge) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

## `switch` expressions

In Java 14+ use [switch expressions](https://openjdk.org/jeps/361) to make your intentions more clear.

```java
  public List<Competition> getCompetitionss( final String competAge ) {
    return
        switch ( competAge )  {
            case COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 -> List.of( … ) ;
            case COMPETITION_AGE_30_40 -> List.of( CompetitionRoller ) ;
            default -> List.of() ;
        }
    }
  }
```

But this would be only imperceptibly faster to execute, if at all. The real benefit is making the code crystal clear to the reader.

If you really want to optimize, consider establishing those `List` objects just once, outside your method. But even that will not help performance if the compiler were to make that optimization itself (I don’t know if it does or not).

Beware of premature optimization. Your Question’s code is *highly* unlikely to impact your app’s performance.

### Example code

Define an enum for your `Competition` objects.

```java
package work.basil.example.competition;

public enum Competition { NATATION , FOOT , HAND , ROLLER }
```

Define the class with your logic.

```java
package work.basil.example.competition;

import java.util.List;

public class CompetitionEx
{
    public static final String COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 = "compet1";
    public static final String COMPETITION_AGE_30_40 = "compet2";

    public List < Competition > getCompetitions ( final String competAge )
    {
        return
                switch ( competAge )
                {
                    case COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 -> List.of ( Competition.NATATION , Competition.FOOT , Competition.HAND , Competition.NATATION );
                    case COMPETITION_AGE_30_40 -> List.of ( Competition.ROLLER );
                    default -> List.of ( );
                };
    }
}
```

Exercise that logic with an `App` class.

```java
package work.basil.example.competition;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App ();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        CompetitionEx compEx = new CompetitionEx () ;
        System.out.println ( compEx.getCompetitionss ( CompetitionEx.COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 ) );
        System.out.println ( compEx.getCompetitionss ( CompetitionEx.COMPETITION_AGE_30_40 ) );
    }
}
```

Results:

```
[NATATION, FOOT, HAND, NATATION]
[ROLLER]
```

## Define lists ahead of time

If you *really* want to optimize, move the list instantiations to an earlier time, to happen once instead of happening on each method call.

I do not know for sure if this is a real optimization, as the compiler could theoretically optimize those hard-coded `List.of` calls.

I trust you would devise better names than `COMP_LIST_LONG` and `COMP_LIST_SHORT`.

```java
public class CompetitionEx
{
    public static final String COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 = "compet1";
    public static final String COMPETITION_AGE_30_40 = "compet2";

    public static final List < Competition > COMP_LIST_LONG = List.of ( Competition.NATATION , Competition.FOOT , Competition.HAND , Competition.NATATION );
    public static final List < Competition > COMP_LIST_SHORT = List.of ( Competition.ROLLER );

    public List < Competition > getCompetitions ( final String competAge )
    {
        return
                switch ( competAge )
                {
                    case COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 -> COMP_LIST_LONG;
                    case COMPETITION_AGE_30_40 -> COMP_LIST_SHORT;
                    default -> List.of ( );
                };
    }
}
```

## `Map`

Rather than write your method `getCompetitions`, you could just as well define a `Map` object to pair a list with each of your possible strings.

As for performance, I can't say specifically. The concrete `Map` implementation returned by `Map.of` is not specified, and may vary by different versions of Java. But I think we can trust its `get` method would be very fast.

```java
public class CompetitionEx
{
    public static final String COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 = "compet1";
    public static final String COMPETITION_AGE_30_40 = "compet2";

    public static final List < Competition > COMP_LIST_LONG = List.of ( Competition.NATATION , Competition.FOOT , Competition.HAND , Competition.NATATION );
    public static final List < Competition > COMP_LIST_SHORT = List.of ( Competition.ROLLER );

    public static final Map < String, List < Competition > > MAP_STRING_TO_COMP_LIST =
            Map.of (
                    COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 , COMP_LIST_LONG ,
                    COMPETITION_AGE_30_40 , COMP_LIST_SHORT
            );
}
```

The `App` code changes to this:

```java
    private void demo ( )
    {
//        CompetitionEx compEx = new CompetitionEx () ;
//        System.out.println (compEx.getCompetitions ( CompetitionEx.COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 ) );
//        System.out.println (compEx.getCompetitions ( CompetitionEx.COMPETITION_AGE_30_40 ) );

        System.out.println ( CompetitionEx.MAP_STRING_TO_COMP_LIST.get ( CompetitionEx.COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 ) );
        System.out.println ( CompetitionEx.MAP_STRING_TO_COMP_LIST.get ( CompetitionEx.COMPETITION_AGE_30_40 ) );
    }
```

Results are the same.

This approach works with earlier versions of Java.

The `Map.of` call is in Java 9+.

In Java 8, you can replace that `Map.of` call. You would construct a `HashMap`, populate its entries, and then pass to [`Collections.unmodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-).

---

By the way, using strings as flags such as `COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 = "compet1"` is brittle. Consider using enums instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it's exactly meaning when you say "in the best way"
but here's an example of making search conditions as input instead of hard coding,  and combining multiple conditions in a pipeline:

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CompetitionMain {
    private static List<Competition> competList = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        competList.add(new CompetitionFoot(18, "footA"));
        competList.add(new CompetitionFoot(30, "footA"));
        competList.add(new CompetitionFoot(40, "footA"));
        competList.add(new CompetitionHand(18, "handA"));
        competList.add(new CompetitionHand(30, "handA"));
        competList.add(new CompetitionHand(40, "handA"));

        List<Competition> ageList = findByAge(competList, 18);
        List<Competition> nameList = findByName(ageList, "footA");
        for (Competition competition : nameList) {
            System.out.println(competition.name);
        }
    }

    public static List<Competition> findByAge(List<Competition> competitions, int age) {
        return competitions.stream().filter(competition -> competition.age == age).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


    public static List<Competition> findByName(List<Competition> competitions, String name) {
        return competitions.stream().filter(competition -> competition.name.equals(name)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}

abstract class Competition {
    public int age;
    public String name;

    public Competition(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }


}

class CompetitionFoot extends Competition {
    public CompetitionFoot(int age, String name) {
        super(age, name);
    }
    // additional fields
}

class CompetitionHand extends Competition {
    public CompetitionHand(int age, String name) {
        super(age, name);
    }
    // additional fields
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Best way* is not well defined, isn't it?
Anyway, constructing a static map for the predefined values may be one of the best choices.

Given:

```
public enum Competition { NATATION , FOOT , HAND , ROLLER }
```

we can write:

```
public static final String COMPETITION_AGE_18_30 = "compet1";
public static final String COMPETITION_AGE_30_40 = "compet2";
public static final Map<String,List<Competition>> m = Map.of(
        COMPETITION_AGE_18_30,List.of(
                Competition.NATATION,
                Competition.FOOT,
                Competition.HAND,
                Competition.NATATION),
        COMPETITION_AGE_30_40, List.of(Competition.ROLLER));

public List<Competition> getCompetitionss(String competAge) {
    return m.getOrDefault(competAge, List.of());
 }
```

The method that computes the value is very simple, readable and does not need to be refactored in anyway as the construction of the static `Map` provides the mapping for the defined values.